# EXCEL multiple filters pivot table with changing data

Tags: excel, pivot

I have a set of data and my conditions are:
Column 1 begins with "000000"
Column 3 begins with "50"
Column 4 count is less than "6"
Column 5 sum is greater than "10000"

since there are count and sum columns i need two value filters (to be filtered again) in the pivot table.

Retain items options: None
Classic Pivot table Layout checked

PS of course i refresh sheets when i change data!

Answer (score 0):

You have to 'Refresh' the pivot once the source is changed.